# Journey builder Rest API publish returns draft status

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I have created a script using the Journey Builder/Interaction Rest API. When I have multiple versions of a journey and I publish using `POST /interaction/v1/interactions/publishAsync/{id}?versionNumber={versionNumber}` [endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postPublishInteractionById.htm) sometimes it returns a journey with the status of "Draft".

For example, after I publish 2 versions of the same journey, I can see the status of both versions change from "ScheduledToPublish" to one being "Published" and the other one is "Draft".

Comment: If you try to activate this in the UI are you getting any errors? that return it to draft?

Comment: When I try to activate this with the UI it does return an error. (just a general error message with no details)
But activating with the UI is not what returns the version to draft. After I make the publish POST with the API that is what makes the version a draft.

Comment: The error is the issue